# How to do named multiqueries using C# Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, fql.multiquery

I'm updating some legacy code from the old 3.0 version of the C# Facebook SDK to the new 5.3.2 version.

On http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/
it shows that you can do a multiquery like:

```
"query1":"SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=12345678"
"query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"
```

In the old API, you'd just have a Dictionary where each query was paired up with it's name:

```
"page_admin_list","SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_admin where uid = 1234567890"
"permissions_response","SELECT uid, read_stream, status_update, photo_upload, publish_stream, offline_access FROM permissions WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM #page_admin_list)"
```

In each of the examples, notice the # in the nested query.  However, I'm unsure how to accomplish this with the new syntax since it is only accepting string[] as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Facebook C# SDK v6 you can execute named queries using the following method.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("fql",
    new
        {
            q = new
            {
                id = "SELECT uid from user where uid=me()",
                name = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #id)",
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer (**edit**: *this applies to the earlier versions of the sdk, for version 6 and above see prabir's answer*) : 
I have to reference each query by #query0, #query1, etc...

Or I can use the Get() method rather than the Query() method

```
var queries = 
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "FamDamly", "select uid from family where profile_id = me()" },
        { "FamDetails", "select uid, first_name from user where uid in #FamDamly" }
    };
client.Get(queries);
```